# Decouple geometry and plotting resolution for scientific visualization

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, visualization

I am currently writing an application that performs a physical simulation on surfaces and then plots the resulting values on the surfaces (typical scientific visualization).

For those calculations, the users draw a lot (up to 10000) parametric surfaces (like Polygons, cones, cylinders, etc), on which the simulation is performed.

I am currently facing the following problem:

**How can I decouple the visualization mesh from the calculation mesh?**

To reduce calculation time, users can choose the resolution of the calculation. But even if the calculation resolution is very low (say, 1m distance between calculation points), the mesh that is used to visualize the surfaces must be higher in resolution (e.g. to make sure that round surfaces are still round).

That means I need to map the calculation mesh to the visualization mesh.

We can also have the reverse situation: A calculation mesh that is much higher in resolution than the visualization mesh

What would be the best way to do so?

The framework in question would be WebGL 2. I cannot use a framework like Paraview.

I am new to graphics programming, and I have figured out the following approaches:

1. Use Textures
   For this approach, the results to be plotted would be put into a texture that would then simply be applied to the surface
   However, I'm not sure how to do that, because the Mesh isn't regular / structures, so I'd need some kind of automatic mesh unwrapping / uv unwrapping / uv parametrization algorithm like OptCuts or XAtlas?

This would work for both situations, i.e. visualization mesh finer than calculation mesh and calculation mesh finer than visualization mesh

Another point is that I've seen that usually multiple textures are compressed into a texture atlas for efficiency reasons. Would that also be necessary for the problem size I've outlined?

2. Use Vertex Colours and a custom interpolation algorithm

For this approach, an interpolation algorithm would map the results from the calculation mesh to the visualization mesh and assign vertex colours.
This doesn't require a mesh unwrapping / uv unwrapping / uv parametrization algorithm, because it could happen in the parameter space of the surface.

However, this wouldn't work for the "calculation mesh finer than visualization mesh" scenario, because the resolution is limited as we are only assigning colours to the vertices and interpolation happens between the vertices

3. Some kind of custom fragment shader?

From my research, it seems like a custom fragment shader could be the place to perform some mapping from one mesh to the other. However, I have no idea how one would do that.

Is there anything obvious I've missed? What would be the best approach and why?
Is this maybe already a solved problem? I can imagine that ParaView would have similar problems?